# Rails 3.2.13 link_to post request doesn't work links to the index page instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problems with the like_to method to make a post request.

I am following the book Agile web development with rails 4th and try to make a post request if the user click on the image. 
My code is as following

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(product.image_url), line_items_path(:product_id => product), :method => :post) %>
```

Some people said that we need to do some configuration of JS tag to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

I did it, but the link is still go to the index page.

I also change the symbol to "create" or "post", but still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I have been stuck on this for long and can't find a way out. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's confusing, you should take things one by one.

First, I don't understand why you add this tag `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`. Normally you should have in you layout/application.html.rb file a line that look like this `<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>`. This line is the inclusion of your JS manifest and in a default configuration it should be enough. You can read more about assets pipeline and JS manifests in Rails guides (see links bellow)

Second, about your link, I suggest this syntax instead:

```
<%= link_to(line_items_path(product), :method => :post) do %>
  <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see I moved `image_tag` in a block, its much easier to read. Also `line_items_path` should work by passing directly the product record to it (no need for a hash, Rails will do the magic).

Please try, and is this does not work out of the box, edit your question to include your route.eb file

Guides Rails 4: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Guides Rails 3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/

Comment: Hi Ben, sorry didn't phrase the problem well. the javascript_include_tag is in the layout/application.html.emb and it does work now! thank you.

Comment: Ok goos :) If my answer helped don't forget to validate it